# What is raster size of an image?

Tags: image, raster

I am given two images

1st one has raster size 1000
2nd one has raster size 1500

How to understand this numbers? Images are really small and embedded in pdf. I can't detect visually that one is smaller than the second one.

Comment: images are two dimensional. they cannot have just a single "size" measurement, unless that's total pixels. And the number of pixels says NOTHING about what the two-dimensional size is. `1x1500`, `2x750`, `3x500` are all "1500" in size

Comment: All what the report gives me is "raster size" for image 1 is 1000 and for the second is 1500. I am trying to understand what this means. Doesn't make sense for me neither